# Angular 7 - Service worker won't register

Tags: service-worker, angular7

The ngsw-worker.js and ngsw.json files are generated in when starting the project with ng build --prod but when i check for the service worker in application none is registered

Comment: you got an error? are you running on a safe URL? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https

Comment: I didn't have an error and I was running on a safe URL. I used the manual solution for register the service worker. 
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(() => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && environment.production) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/ngsw-worker.js');
  }
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
But if you know another better way please share :)